# Disable sort on sortable element except connectWith

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is this possible to disable sort on 'sortable' element but sort still work with 'connectWith' ?

Answer (score 3):

This will return an element in list1 to it's original location if it is not dropped on list2 (I call this a self-drop).

```
$("#list1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected-fields",
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
        // Don't allow resorting in list1... would call cancel here, but there is a jquery 1.7 bug so we
        // need to do the check here but do the cancel in "stop" below. @see http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6054
        $(this).sortable("option", "selfDrop", $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] == this);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var $sortable = $(this);
        if ($sortable.sortable("option", "selfDrop")) {
            $sortable.sortable('cancel');
            return;
        }
    }
});

$("#list2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected-fields"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would then just remove the original sortable logic, and apply a class that is attached to a single sortable. So, for example, you have three functions for the two list you are sorting. If one is sort=disabled, then remove the sortable class that has the options conenctWith, and apply a single sort class to the list you were connected with. If that one is to be stopped, then do the same with the other.

Example:

```
$('sortBoth').sortable({connectWith: $('.sortListToConnect)});

$('.sortList2').sortable();

$('.sortList3').sortable();
```

Remove or add the class to each list accordingly for how you need it to function. A simple way to handle it. Hopefully I stated it clear enough, in a quick manner. Happy coding:)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code for `disable sortable`:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "disable" );
```

You can learn more from this [Link](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)

And this [Link](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-disable) for `disable` Method.

Comment: i want to sort only with connectWith not disable sortable.

Comment: can you provide me with HTML and the Javascript code, I think I can help

Comment: i haven't any code. check http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists.  i want left column sort with right column but left column doesn't sort with left column itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can cancel the items in the left columns from self-sorting, and still use them for connectWith

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel